# Get SQL a Django model has (or would call) on .save()

Tags: sql, django, django-models

How can you get the SQL for a Django model's .save(), i.e.

```
from django.db import models

class MyM(models.Model):
   text = models.TextField()
```

How can you get the SQL that would be created/used in the following scenario:

```
 >>> m = MyM(text="123")
 >>> m.save()
 # What SQL Django just run?
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From the Django FAQ:

How can I see the raw SQL queries Django is running?
Make sure your Django DEBUG setting is set to True. Then, just do this:

```
>>> from django.core.db import db  
>>> db.queries  
[{'sql': 'SELECT polls_polls.id,polls_polls.question,polls_polls.pub_date FROM polls_polls',   
'time': '0.002'}]
```

db.queries is only available if DEBUG is True. It's a list of dictionaries in order of      query execution. Each dictionary has the following:
`sql`--The raw SQL statement
`time` -- How long the statement took to execute, in seconds.
db.queries includes all SQL statements -- INSERTs, UPDATES, SELECTs, etc.

Comment: Thanks, DrDee. Would the most recent query then be db.queries[-1]? (or, if that's an iterator, list(db.queries)[-1])?

Comment: Here's the FAQ in question: http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/faq/models/#how-can-i-see-the-raw-sql-queries-django-is-running -- note it's `from django.db import connection` and `connection.queries`

Comment: I suspect db.queries[-1], but just give it a shot and see what happens.

Comment: For no apparent reason the INSERTs aren't showing up ... but SELECTs are. Strange. I'll tinker. In any event - this ought to work - thanks.

Answer (score 8):

If you want get the insert statement for model before saving - you can use the following code (checked on django 1.4)

```py
from django.db import connection
from django.db.models import sql

def object_to_query(objects):
    if isinstance(objects, (list, tuple)
    values = obj._meta.local_fields
    q = sql.InsertQuery(obj)
    q.insert_values(values, [obj])
    compiler = q.get_compiler('default')
    # Normally, execute sets this, but we don't want to call execute
    setattr(compiler, 'return_id', False)
    stmts = compiler.as_sql()
    stmt = [stmt % params for stmt, params in stmts]
    return stmt[0]
```

Comment: This should be the correct answer. There is not much point in looking at the save statement after it has already run, when one is concerned about how it alters the data and we want to make sure it is not doing anything weird.

Comment: This answer has a syntax error in the `if` statement...

Answer (score 4):

```py
from django.db.models import sql, Model
from typing import List


def _escape_sql_param(param):
    if type(param) is str:
        return f"'{param}'"
    return str(param)


# noinspection PyProtectedMember
def model_to_insert_sql(models: List[Model]):
    fields = models[0]._meta.local_fields
    q = sql.InsertQuery(models[0])
    q.insert_values(fields, models)

    compiler = q.get_compiler('default')
    # Normally, execute sets this, but we don't want to call execute
    setattr(compiler, 'return_id', False)
    raw_statements = compiler.as_sql()

    mixed_statements = [statement % tuple(_escape_sql_param(param) for param in params)
                        for statement, params in raw_statements]
    return mixed_statements
```

Then call it such as

```
model_to_insert_sql([your_model_1, your_model_2])
```

for a bulk insert. If only want a single insert, call it as

```
model_to_insert_sql([your_model])
```

p.s. @Kerrigan's answer cannot compile, and does *not* work with string types...

Answer (score 2):

Just run `python manage.py sqlall APP_NAME`.